# Coldfusion Spreadsheet Blank Cells

Tags: excel, coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I'm trying to write a script to upload an excel sheet into a database, but I'm stuck on a small issue. The script needs to be dynamic so that it doesn't need to change to upload a different excel sheet, simply the sheet must follow the same convention as before.

So, by doing:

```
<cfloop from="2" to="#sheet.rowcount#" index="row">
```

It will loop to the end of the rows, no?

Plot twist: I have to convert blank cells into "N/A"

Easy enough:

```
<cfif SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col) EQ "">
    <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"N/A",row,col) />
</cfif>
```

Issue: this causes dozens of rows to appear on my dummy output (at the end, after the rows have stopped containing anything)

```
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A

N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
```

Very much repeated. The sheet is 56 rows long, but this has to exceed 100. I fear changing the blank cells into "N/A" is the culprit, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the complete file, and unfortunately I must not show the excel sheet. However it is 56 rows, and 17 columns.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="derp.xlsx" name="sheet"> <!--- edit src --->
<!--- 17 columns wide 56 rows --->
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="2" to="#sheet.rowcount#" index="row">
        <cfloop from="1" to="17" index="col"> <!--- multi row selection (edit based on excel sheet) --->
        <cfif SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col) EQ "">
            <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"N/A",row,col) />
        </cfif>
        <cfoutput>#SpreadSheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col)#</cfoutput><br />
        </cfloop>
        <br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

How can I convert blank cells to "N/A" without the script surpassing the `rowcount`?

Comment: If you cfdump sheet.rowcount right after the cfspreadsheet tag, what is the value?  Also, if you simply output the value of row in your outer loop, what is the last number you get?

Comment: It's returning 100, and I don't know why. Like I said, there's only 56 rows of actual content. Is `sheet.rowcount` not doing what I think it's doing?

Comment: can you add a space into a cell in row 105 (or something after 100) and then delete it? Maybe it's reading the last line that had an edit?

Comment: @MattBusche that worked but I have no idea why -- the issue isn't with the code it's how the excel file is read??

Comment: I've barely used cfspreadsheet, but I would say that would be the reason. This is a really hacky solution, but you could loop backward from `sheet.rowcount` and check each cell if it's blank and once you find a row that has a value then you can use that as your new `sheet.rowcount`. Not a great solution, but would work.

Comment: This question and answer say it should ignore empty rows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058144/cfspreadsheet-fails-to-read-empty-rows

Comment: If you wouldn't mind posting this as a solution? As it did solve my issue, you deserve the checkmark and an upvote from me @MattBusche

Comment: *It will loop to the end of the rows, no?* No, it won't because that is a **logical** row number, not physical. Why not just read the sheet into a query, then loop through the query as usual? (Disclaimer, I am working on two things at once, so it is possible I missed something obvious .. but I am not sure I understand the goal).

Comment: I would argue that @Leigh solution should be used as that makes more sense in this context

Comment: Could you show me an example? I'm not quite following

Comment: @RUJordan - IF I understand the goal correctly (read values from a spreadsheet), just use action=read with the query attribute. Something like `<cfspreadsheet src="c:/path/to/file.xls" query="qData" sheet="1" />` will read the values in sheet 1 and populate a query with the sheet values.

Comment: @Leigh thanks for the tip. I'll try, but I have to insert this into a normalized db so I might have to keep the nested loop for sheer indentitycol relationship

Comment: In that case, I suggest loading the spreadsheet contents into a staging table.  Do whatever is necessary in the staging table and then update the real tables from the staging table.

Comment: Yes, I am big fan of staging tables instead of direct inserts. Too easy to hose the db with direct insert. Staging tables give you a lot more flexibility and much better error handling. Do all your validation, then insert everything in a single transaction.

Comment: @RUJordan - Can you explain what identitycol relationship exists with the imported values? It is possible there is an easier/more robust option. But whichever approach you use, do not use the **logical** row count, as it will not yield consistent results. BTW, I think the original problem was due to using the *logical* row count, while at the same time *adding* rows by using `SpreadsheetSetCellValue`, which change the row count as you looped, leading to unexpected results.

Comment: I have a table schema like: `states [id, statename, stateabbr]`, `questions [id, questiontext]`, `responses [id, responsetext]`, and `QandA [id, sid, rid, qid, group]` (there are more columns but they don't matter right now. Basically the first column is a list of statenames, the first row is a question, and all the intermingling rows are answers. Questions, responses, and state IDs are all unique. my query makes sure of that. So this script is to upload new questions without having to delete the whole DB and start fresh each time new data needs to be uploaded

Comment: How does the query enforce uniqueness? So far it sounds like you could do the same thing with a staging table. I typically insert all spreadsheet data into a staging table. Then use JOIN's to various tables to identify what is "new" versus "changed". Then it is easy to add or update all records with a few queries. The basic update/remove/add concept is [described in option #2 here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10716267/104223). You may only need the "add new" portion, but the concept is the same. Put everything into a table, then use SQL to validate or process the data in a single batch.

Comment: *How does the query enforce uniqueness?* More specifically, since that code is not included in the OP, I am trying to get better visual of the current process, so I could offer more specific advice on how you might approach it with a staging table OR modify the current code.

Comment: It uses a query (psuedo query here) to check if a value already exists before every insert (IF NOT EXIST [value in table] INSERT value in table])

Comment: IMO the "insert if not exists ..." construct is much easier with a staging table. A simple UPDATE (join on "value") identifies existing id's. Anything without an ID is "new" and gets INSERT'ed. The idea is use set based sql to process the entire batch, rather than one record at a time. That said, you could still use the loop approach. But I see no reason to use `SpreadsheetGetCellValue`. Just read the values into a query, then loop through it and apply the same logic. Only difference is you have all of the raw data up front, in a single query, versus grabbing them one cell at a time.